# .getjson results not displaying

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying to write a very simple autosuggest type function so that, whenever a user enters a value into the search input, a list of matching results appear in below (In a ul with the id of playlist).

```
$("#ep_search").keydown(function() {

    var term = $("#ep_search").val();
        url = "includes/live_search.php?jsoncallback=&term=" + term;

    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        $.each(data.items, function(item){
            $("<li>").text(item.title).appendTo("#playlist ul");
        });
    });

});
```

Using chrome's developer tools, I can see that I am getting back results:

```
([{"title":"Episode 4: Title"},{"title":"Episode 3: Title"},{"title":"Episode 2: Title"},{"title":"Episode 1: Title"}])
```

However, nothing is displaying on the page?

Am I missing something crucial here? I'm new to working with JSON requests.

Comment: Wow! Thankyou all for the answers so far. I'll have to try these out after I get home this evening,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your url is wrong, so the server-response is missing the function-name.

The response should look something like this:

```
jQuery12345(yourJson)
```

But by the wrong url there is no value for jsoncallback sended to the server(the value is generated by jQuery and the server should use it as function-name in the response)

---

Use either:

```
url = "includes/live_search.php?jsoncallback=?&term=" + term;
```

(you're missing the question-mark for jsoncallback)

```
<?php
  //live_search.php 
   echo $_GET['jsoncallback'].'('.json_encode($someObject).')';
?>
```

---

Or

```
url = "includes/live_search.php?term=" + term;
```

(you don't need the jsoncallback-parameter, it's not a X-Domain-Request. Let the server respond with the pure JSON)

```
<?php
  //live_search.php 
   echo json_encode($someObject);
?>
```

---

your $.each() should look like this:

```
$.each(data, function(index,item){
            $("<li>").text(item.title).appendTo("#playlist ul");
        });
```

(The first argument passed to the callback is the index, not the current item...what will be the 2nd argument)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `data` is itself an array:

```
([{"title":"Episode 
 ^-- array
```

I'm not sure where the parentheses come from, they're probably just a copy'n'paste thing so I'll ignore them.

Try this:

```
$.each(data, function(item){
    // ...
```

Comment: That looks to be identical to his code.  Did you mean to remove `.items`?

Comment: @kingjiv: Yes I did and now have, you're quick! You commented while I was fixing my typo.

Answer (score 1):

`data.items` doesn't appear to be defined.  If you look at your JSON, it is just an array, not an object with `items`.

Comment: the JSON is not an array, it's no JSON

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things going on here. First is that your request is formatted for [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) but live_search.php is not padding the JSON output with a function name. This is probably because you did not set the 'jsoncallback' param to "?" in your request .  However, since you are making a cross-domain request (Same Origin) you don't need to use JSONP.  You can have list_search.php return regular JSON without the outer function padding.  You can open up live_search.php, remove code that outputs the $_GET['jsoncallback'] variable as well as the surrounding parenthesis.  The resulting output should look like this:

```
{"title":"Episode 4: Title"},{"title":"Episode 3: Title"},{"title":"Episode 2: Title"},{"title":"Episode 1: Title"}
```

Also, your $.each iterator is missing the second parameter in the callback function.  See [jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) docs.  I've also provided an example below.

```
$("#ep_search").keydown(function() {
    var term = $("#ep_search").val();
    url = "includes/live_search.php?term=" + term;

    $.getJSON(url, function(data) { 
        $.each(data, function(idx, ele){
            $("<li />").text(ele.title).appendTo("#playlist ul");
        });
    });
});
```